# Making background images responsive - fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am using `fullpage.js` for parallax scrolling. Is it possible to make the background images `responsive` in nature when i `re-size` my `window`.

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Below is the example i am using.
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/backgrounds.html

If you notice each of my `section` has the `background-size` property with `cover`, but its still not responsive when i `re-size`.

```
#section0,
#section1,
#section2,
#section3{
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by responsive? Do you want the image width to always fit the window width?

Comment: @LeBen  yes... the images should fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look i don't know too much about **fullpage.js**
But i don know about resizing image according to your window size.....
first of all download any image and i named it sa.jpg

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #box{   
            width:100%;
        }
        <!--This class is added to img element to make it responsive -->
        img.responsive{
            max-width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div id="box">
             <img src ="sa.jpg" class="responsive"></img>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In above code we kept image within **#box** div. and we also added responsive named class to img element.Assign it a max-width value of 100%. This allows the width
to adjust to the browser width changes. Next, add a dynamic height property to the class.

Above code is responsive for img element..

Now if you want to use background image css property and resize your image according to screen size

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style style type="text/css"> 
        #box{   
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-image:url("sa.jpg");
            background-size:100% auto;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        <!--img.responsive{max-width:100%;height:auto}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works best for me

```
background-position: 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
```