# Making my images fit to the width of browser

Tags: html, css

How can i make my images fit to the width of the browser width. When i re-size my browser, i want the image too re-size according to browser width.

```
#section0,
#section1,
#section2,
#section3{
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Defining each sectino background and styles 
* --------------------------------------- */
#section0{
    background-image: url(http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/panoramic/img/background/f.jpg);
}
#section1{
    background-image: url(http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/panoramic/img/background/f.jpg);
}
#section2{
    background-image: url(http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/panoramic/img/background/f.jpg);
}
#section3 h1{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Below is my codpen... 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lpGkj?editors=110

How can i make the `images` width to equal to browser `width` on re-size.

Comment: Ah...isn't that what `background-size: cover;` does, though? What sort of behaviour are you seeing now? In which browser (version)?

Comment: @Serlite: When i re-size m browser window... the images does not get re-sized.... I am using chrome.

Comment: Set the width of each section equal to a percentage, i.e. `width: 100%;`.

Comment: It looks like you might need to set a width and a height on both html,body and #fullpage, #section0, #section1, #section2, and #section3. Set it to 100% all of them. or Just html, body, div { width: 100%; height: 100% }  @ http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/jwaiF

Comment: @Evan: http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/full/jwaiF/ i saw yours... but it does not scale after a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

In that pen, your background is not showing up because they have no content so their height is 0.

`background-size: cover` is a good solution, but you can also use

`background-size: 100% auto` to keep the background width as 100% even when the aspect ratio (width/height) of the container is smaller than the aspect ratio of the background image.

Comment: @Frank you have to understand that image ratio and screen or element will be most of the time unequal. This answers to your question, bg image will be always 100% width. if you want it too 100% height, then it will stretch/expand image, if this okay to you , then : background-size:100% 100%; will be fine and weird sometimes :) http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/zyFoe

Comment: Thanks, it works... but now it looks weird... is there no compiling solution for this.

Comment: you could try to set a min-height to your section with % padding so it would have a similar ratio to start with

Comment: I saw your fiddle...  codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/zyFoe and you have set min-height: 100px.... what should it be to have a similar ratio to start with?

Comment: Hello, didn't you try my solution? It works, let's have a look to the fiddle.

Comment: @Frank , for the ratio, you may use a floatting pseudo with a vertical padding in % that takes width as reference : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/details/zyFoe/ min-height, even in % won't be efficient to match at least with ratio. The pseudo will provide your min-height alike :)

Comment: How can i look into the code.. i seem to miss it codepen.io/gcyrillus/details/zyFoe

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the position of the `div`:

```
#section0,
#section1,
#section2,
#section3{
 background-size: cover;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;    
}
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL8Yb/).

When use the Css Cover Background, keep in mind the cross-browser [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts).

Comment: hi, position:fixed seems weird to me, do you intend to pile each one of them ?

Comment: I've understand now your point: you want to make the section div one below the others, always each one full page width and height, right? To accomplish it you have to use JS to set to each Div the window's dimensions and position the top of each one.

Answer (score 0):

I just answer this 
you can check at [Making background images responsive - fullpage.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042930/making-background-images-responsive-fullpage-js/25044378#25044378)
if there is any question regarding responsive you can ask in comments...